# Implementing a Stored Procedure Call with Optional Parameters in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, optional-parameters

I've been trying to find a way to make stored proc calls from Spring 3.0 to Oracle 11.2 with following the items in mind:

- Many of the calls are made to stored procedures that have plethora of
  optional parameters (parameters that have default values).
- There are stored procedures that can have a mix of: `IN`, `OUT`, and/or `IN OUT`.
- I do not need to handle the `OUT`'s.

I would like to be able to call a stored proc with the needed parameters (required and/or optional). In other word, I **do not wish to pass a value** (not even a `null`) to optional parameters to my choosing (it seems like when `null` is being passed programmatically [not in PL/SQL though] to a parameter mapper, the default values don't get used). I have attempted to implement these invocations as many possible ways as I could but nothing has worked:

```
create or replace
procedure update_stored_proc (
h1 in boolean default false,
h2 in number,
h3 in varchar2 default 'H3',
h4 in varchar2 default 'H4',
h5 in varchar2 default 'H5',
h6 in out number
);
```

For `update_stored_proc()`, there is only two required parameters (`h2` and `h6`), and four optional ones. My ultimate goal is to call `update_stored_proc()` by passing `h1`, `h2` and `h6`. Even when I invoking the stored proc via `SimpleJdbcCall` with all the values set, I get an exception:

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(updatingDataSource)
                    .withProcedureName("update_stored_proc")
                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();

simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("h1", OracleTypes.BOOLEAN))
              .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("h2", OracleTypes.NUMBER))
              .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("h3", OracleTypes.VARCHAR))
              .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("h4", OracleTypes.VARCHAR))
              .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("h5", OracleTypes.VARCHAR))
              .declareParameters(new SqlInOutParameter("h6", OracleTypes.NUMBER));

MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("h1", false, OracleTypes.BOOLEAN)
            .addValue("h2", 123, OracleTypes.NUMBER)
            .addValue("h3", "h3", OracleTypes.VARCHAR)
            .addValue("h4", "h4", OracleTypes.VARCHAR)
            .addValue("h5", "h5", OracleTypes.VARCHAR)
            .addValue("h6", "h6", OracleTypes.NUMBER);

simpleJdbcCall.compile();
simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
```

The exception I get indicates that the column type is somehow invalid:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call update_stored_proc(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

I have replaced `OracleTypes` with `Types` and even taken out `withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()` but the error persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question turned out to require several solutions to get to work. First and foremost, Oracle's implementation of SQL standards does not contain `BOOLEAN` type, even though its propriety PL/SQL script language does support it (more reason for the DBA's not to use `BOOLEAN` type in their stored procedures). The solution I came up with was to use an anonymous block, declare a local variable, and assign it to the `BOOLEAN` parameter:

```
DECLARE
  h1_false BOOLEAN := false;
  h6_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  update_stored_proc(
  h1 => h1_false,
  h2 => :h2,
  h6 => h6_
  );
END;
```

Note that I do not care about the value of `h1` (and for that matter, the `OUT` parameter/`h6`) parameter for my particular functionality, but I could imagine by having a simple `IF THEN ELSE` statement, one can assign a binded parameter to `h1`, i.e.

```
DECLARE
  h1_false BOOLEAN;
  h6_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF :h1 THEN
    h1_false = true;
  ELSE
    h1_false = false;
  END IF;

  update_stored_proc(
  h1 => h1_false,
  h2 => :h2,
  h6 => h6_
  );
END;
```

The second issue is the way `Spring` handles the **optional parameters**. If one to declare the optional parameters, then `Spring`'s `SimpleJdbcCall` -- and `StoredProcedure` for that matter -- expects values for those parameters. Therefore, one must take care of these values when they become *available*. Otherwise, when the optional parameter does not have a value, you must pass `NULL` which **will not trigger the *DEFAULT* value of the PL/SQL's parameter to be used**. This means that your query string (in this case an anonymous PL/SQL block) must be **generated dynamically**. So, the anonymous block becomes:

```
DECLARE
  h1_false BOOLEAN := false;
  h6_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  update_stored_proc(
  h1 => h1_false,
  h2 => :h2,
  h6 => h6_
```

I switched to `StoredProcedure` solution rather than `SimpleJdbcCall`, as it turned out to be more simpler. Albeit I must add that I had to *extend* `StoredProcedure` to create a common class for my stored procedure classes and use that extended class for my customized stored procedure classes. In your `StoredProcedure` class, you only declare the required parameters (make sure not to `compile()` the query at this point):

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h2", OracleTypes.NUMBER));
```

**Note**: If you do not need the `OUT` parameter, like in my case, do not include it in your declaration. Otherwise, assign a binding variable, i.e. `h6 => :h6` in the anonymous block and declare it in your `StoredProcedure`, i.e. `declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("h6", OracleTypes.NUMBER));` and make sure to get `:h6` value out when `execute()` returns a `Map<String, Object>`. If your `OUT` value is of `BOOLEAN` type, then I do not know how to retrieve the value.

The remaining **optional parameters** should be dynamically constructed in your `StoredProcedure`. i.e.:

```
if (someObj.getH3() != null) {
  declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h3", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
  paramMap.put("h3", someObj.getH3());
  anonymousPLSQLBlockQueryString += " , h3 => :h3";
}
```

where `paramMap` represents a `Map` that is going to be passed to `StoredProcedure#execute(paramMap)`. You do the same with `h4` and `h5`, and at the end, you have to make sure to properly close the anonymous block query string, i.e.:

```
anonymousPLSQLBlockQueryString += " ); END;";
setSql(anonymousPLSQLBlockQueryString);
setSqlReadyForUse(true);
compile();
```